# Menu items are displayed differently

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I have a multilingual page with the languages Spanish and English.
When I edit the menu items in the backend, my default or original language is English.
Now the menu links in this menu are always displayed in the language that is selected as the language path at the top of the browser bar.
So I have something like https://stage-mydomaini.de/es/adminbereich/structure/menu/manage/main or https://stage-mydomaini.de/en/adminbereich/structure/menu/manage/main.

The menu links are displayed in the path language.
This kind of confuses me, because of course I always try to translate the Spanish link again. Isn't it not intended that the back-end always adapts to the path?

My settings in the speech recognition are the following.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Do any of you have an idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The **Menu language** select box is for the original language of the menu configuration. In your case it seems the correct language should be German because of the label now assigned to it. After you have selected the original language and saved the menu config you can use the tab at the top *Translate Menu* to add a *Label* and *Menu Description* for other languages. This entire translation procedure is only for these two text fields.

Translating the menu items is a completely different process and is part of the content translation system where you need to enable translation of *Custom Menu Links* first. Then you can access the translate operation for each menu item.

Concerning the language detection, you have configured more language detection methods than normally necessary. For the start you need only one, the URL based method, which should also be at the top priority, only surpassed by *Account administration pages*, if you use this feature.